# How do I fill in these holes from curtain rail?

Tags: hole

Bought some curtains that were too heavy and the holder came out of the wall.
What should I use and how, so that it can be repaired and replaced?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Congrats on including some pics! So few think to do that!!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the brick that fixing (rawlplug) goes into.

If the brick is damaged behind the plaster, then anything else you put in there will come out sooner or later.

I would consider, if the brick is sound, gluing (epoxy or similar strong glue) a wooden dowel into the hole - whittled to fit well. Once dry I would pre-drill the dowel (so the screw does not split it) and use a suitable screw.

If the brick is not sound, the epoxy may be sufficient or you will be looking at either re-locating the fixings or doing something with the brick, not easy though.

Comment: Brick? That looks like plaster & lathe to me, with a thick coat of finish plaster over the top. You're thinking that the grey inner level is a cinder block?